# Open/Closed Sets and relatives

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $A \subset X$ is open in $X$ and $X$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $A$ open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

I suppose that is true but it's lack argumentation to me.

if $A$ is open in $X$ then for all $a \in A$ exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that $X \cap B(a;\epsilon) \subset A$. If i assume that $\epsilon$ is such that  $B(a;\epsilon) \subset X$ because $X$ is open then $B(a;\epsilon) \subset A$ for all $a \in A$ and there is, but what ensures that this $\epsilon$ have this propetie for $X$ and $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"... because any $a \in A$ is also $a \in X$."

However, an easier way is from the definition of relatively open:  $A$ relatively open in $X$ means there is an open $\hat{A} \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $A = \hat{A} \cap X$.  $X$ is given open (in $\Bbb{R}^n$) and the intersection of open sets is open, so $A$ is open in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, you know that such a value of $\epsilon$ exists, so let the $\epsilon$ you choose be sufficiently small that $B(a;\epsilon)\cap X\subset A$ and $B(a;\epsilon)\subset X$.